# Расстановка знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите,пожалуйста,нужны ли запятые в следующих предложениях.А затем он пошел за нею(,)как невольник.Зачем она поступила со мною(,)как с беспутной?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Сравнение: А затем он пошел за нею, **как невольник**. Сравнить: А затем он, **как невольник**,  пошел за нею.

2) Обстоятельство образ действия: Зачем она поступила со мною **как с беспутной**?  Входит в основное сообщение, без него семантика предложения не выражена.

Сравнить: Зачем она поступила со мною? (Вариант без обстоятельства).

Comment: Полезные сведения, но очень уж конспективно изложено, не сразу поймешь. О чем вообще п.1 и 2, и как они связаны с вопросом? Сбивают с толку похожие "Сравнение:" и "Сравнить:" Что значит "Вариант без обстоятельства"? Я в конце концов разобрался, но почему не сделать текст более читабельным?

Comment: Наверное, Вы правы,  мне кажется, что  я пишу понятно, но, наверное,  для себя,  не для всех. 1) Хотя два пункта, к примеру,  относятся к двум вопросам. 2) Сравнить - это "для сравнения рассмотрим  вариант с перестановкой, так как сравнительный оборот может занимать любую позицию, в отличие от обстоятельства, обычно следующего после глагола. 3) Вааринт без обстоятельства: убрали обстоятельство, и предложение утратило смысл.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: М_Г,а по мне,так всё понятно и доступно изложено.